# Docker error response from Daemon

Tags: docker

I'm following the instructions from https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/docker-quickstart and
when I run

```
sudo docker run --rm --name eosio -d -p 8888:8888 -p 9876:9876 -v   
/tmp/work:/work -v /tmp/eosio:/mnt/dev/data eosio/eos-dev /bin/bash -c 
"nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::wallet_api_plugin --plugin 
eosio::wallet_plugin --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin 
eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin 
eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin -d /mnt/dev/data -- 
http-server-address=0.0.0.0:8888 --access-control-allow-origin=* --contracts-console"
```

I'm getting

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Failed to inspect container 4d13c13b0e91bc79aaff44e9b185ae4d3b5bd69c0b19e988cf0b042e92db8bd3: Error response 
from daemon: readlink /var/lib/docker/overlay2/l: invalid argument.
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to corrupted images. 
If you're using mac, you can resolve it by going to Preferences menu, click on Reset tab, and click "Remove all data." Then run docker pull eosio/eos-dev again.

Comment: Nice work, can you mark this as solved with the checkmark button?